# Should Testers be called QA?

Tags: quality-assurance, terminology, tester

At many places, Quality Assurance(QA) is used as a designation/title for Testers.

In general, the difference I got between QA and Tester is as below:

[QA supposed to be more focused on preventing defects in the first place by fixing the process itself whereas Tester is more concerned about finding defects as an after the event](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37793/what-is-the-difference-between-quality-assurance-engineer-and-a-tester)

The problem I have is that this definition means that calling Testers as QA is wrong:

> How does QA assure quality?

Testing does not assure quality. I have never met anyone with QA in their job title who actually assures quality.

> How does QA prevent defects?

The activities I can think of falls under Testers activities. None of the activities I can think of prevent defects.

> Can Tester really assure Quality? If yes, How?

I don't know any way that a Tester can assure quality. Testers can only find potential defects. They can't prevent defects. They can't fix defects.

Testers can report their perspective on the quality of the product to their team, and they can help their team to make the product as good as possible.

**Is QA a right term to be used for Tester?**

Comment: @AlexeyR. No, It doesn't answer my question(s). I am not asking the difference. I did my research and have also added in the question itself. My main question: Is QA a right term to be used for people doing testing? How does QA assuring Quality? How are QA preventing defects? and a few successive questions related to it. 

Can you please read the question again. Feel free to ask again if you are still not clear.

Comment: While the question emphasizes a bit different point indeed, I believe the answers for mentioned question are also applicable to your one.

Comment: I am not able to get how is it answering this question too. Can you please elaborate. Or share a link to that specific answer(s) for reference. As I have read many answers on that above question.

Comment: Why do you question the term QA or Tester? At many places they have old traditional titles that do not match the actual work people do. I could give my oppinion, but it greatly depends on the reason you want to define this better. Why does the "correct"  term really matter to you?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal If it's just old traditional titles, then it's a different story. But I want to know if there is any logical reason behind using it interchangeably.

Comment: @Niels just because it's not followed at some places it doesn't take away the actual intensions of bring in these designations . This question helps us in revisiting the process and try to look for the real skills when hiring a QA or tester . I worked a QA and as a tester . When I was working as QA approving product release , ensuring new features etc were my duty . But in test role , I could just recommend , the final decision was done by developer .

Comment: During last years linux sys admins are renamed to Devops and no one cares. You don't need to care either. People don't care about correct words in IT. They use it only to manipulate others.

Comment: @Nakilon well it sad to see you don't care how did a sys admin transition to DevOps though. I bet you don't even know they don't have the same responsibilities based on your statement. By knowing these responsibilities, you will be able to do your job effectively, that's what I believe.

Comment: @ky-chan, it's sad to see how you talk nonsense about me while being unable to even understand what I said. You're probably just an angry sysadmin or idk why such ignorance.

Comment: @Nakilon I'm not trying to make it as argument though.  Also, I am not a sysadmin by nature but I do have an experience of being a sysadmin before transitioning as devops. And then become an automation tester after that as a programmer (which is my current job). I'm not trying to judge you that's why I said it is based on your statement, and if it offended you, I'm sorry for that. What I am trying to say is that, it will be very hard to understand the task that will assign to you if you just ignore how these traditional title evolves.

Comment: I agree with @ky-chan. Blindly following the traditional role doesn't make any sense. Each role should be used wisely and appropriately at right place. Each has its own set of responsibilities.

Comment: Please comment the reason for closing the question. As I mentioned above, it's not duplicate with the one mentioned by @AlexeyR., answers given there are not clearing the questions I mentioned here. If there is any, please share that link. It's not right to just follow traditional roles without knowing or understanding logic behind it. If anyone else agree with me, then please vote to re-open. For people who don't have privilege to  re-open can upvote this comment or add your views in comments.

Comment: @ky-chan nothing "evolves" into each other. System administration, DevOps and Testing are different things. My comment was about that people do not understand these words and apply them by trend, hype, and there is nothing you can do about it. There are 100 specialists in marketing and sales who make more and more articles and official documents using these words per 1 man who really understands what they mean. For example "DevOps is not a job or position, it's a practice" was an answer given on this website years ago but the whole world thinks different.

Comment: @Nakilon I see, I understand what you are trying to say and I am sorry if I took your first comment on the wrong way. Also, looking back, "quality assurance", is also more like a practice more than a job too. I do well know that these words are just a trend, but the responsibilities with these titles are evolving though (that's for my opinion). That's why I think JAINAM is trying to ask this question in order for QA, Tester to understand their role, not just blindly following it because it was given.

Answer (score 3):

I look at it this way: **software testing is a part of quality assurance**.

In a nutshell, quality assurance is something that can be done throughout the entire SDLC. With the current trend of Agile and DevOps practices, almost every tester is doing some form of QA by default.

Testers are involved in many (if not all) team meetings so they contribute to quality even before development starts, like in refinement meetings (bringing up scenarios no-one though of) or by making a case for unit/automated testing and related best practices. This way the **process** improves - even if it's just handling stand-up meetings differently - by input from testers (and others).
Also hindsight is quite important: testers can be the protagonist to set up specific processes (such as incident retrospectives, metrics or reporting) that are targeted at improving quality over the long term.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views @FDM. What do you mean by the statement "almost every tester is doing some form of QA by default"? I think with that perspective, we should say everyone on the team is doing some form of QA, why just testers?

Comment: @JAINAM Yes everyone hopefully is, or at least can be, participating to quality, but I'm talking about testers only because that is what your question is about.

Comment: So, We can say Software development is also a part of Quality Assurance. right?

Comment: @JAINAM Testing by definition exists to improve quality (in a specific manner) while development is another type of activity. However, developers (and development as activity) can contribute to quality in many ways. If you want to read that as 'being part of', go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

> Testers can only find potential defects.

This seems a very narrow view on what activities testers could do in a team. I think the testing discipline is mainly about managing risks. Designing and executing test-cases is just one path of reducing risk. Risk analyses and defect root-cause analysis are example activities that testers could (and probably should) facilitate, both can prevent issues before they occur.

> Is QA a right term to be used for Tester?

No, because both are wrong. I think in software development we should loose the term "Tester" and "Quality Assurance", because both have a very negative feel historically:

- Quality Assurance and Control: Part of a quality management system, following a formal process and ISO standards. Adding lots of overhead and slowing us down.
- Tester: Low skilled click monkeys that we can give the boring stuff, because he/she is just a tester. The lowest in the development food chain.

You are more than just a tester, you are not a label. (Check out [Damian Synadinos presentation on "More Than That"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3JJ0fvzfq8))

The [Agile Testing](https://agiletester.ca/) and the [Modern Testing](https://www.angryweasel.com/ABTesting/modern-testing-principles/) movements talk about product quality and mature quality cultures. Therefore I have changed my tittle to **Software Quality Specialist**. Where I assist a product development team with Process, Structural and Functional qualilty.

Answer (score 1):

> Is QA a right term to be used for Tester?

Well `tester` is for traditional called for responsible of testing the product thoroughly. Although for many years, hiring lots of manual testers are getting more expensive, so the term QA Tester has been emerged. With QA tester (that what it is called in my country), we are doing more on automation things. Creating automation scripts for the repetitive task, ensuring it run on different environment using Jenkins without the need of many people doing it at the same time.  It can also detect earlier broken functionalities in the app, if you establish your automation right (really nice to have when you are doing regression test). It save a lot of resources and time. That's why more company are preferring more on QA tester than a manual tester.

> Can Tester really assure Quality? If yes, How?

Well I am not sure how to respond with this question though. But as tester, your job is to ensure that the app is not buggy, by doing what you think the user will do. So with this, you can assure that you are not being biased. That's why when we create a test cases, it should not solely be reflected on what these new feature/functionalities can do but more like on what can user can do with this functionalities.

The key point of these two terms though are the same. `Ensuring the quality of the product/app`. No matter how different the approached they used, it will always goes down to that.

Answer (score 0):

As a software testing company, mostly QA and Testers are interrelated term but as a QA, the responsibilities have also increased. Nowadays client expects a QA to work as per project requirement i.e as a manual engineer, automation engineer, dev ops etc. As the world is changing, its is very important to justify tasks and ensure a defect free product.

Happy Testing!!

Comment: How do you ensure a defect-free product?

Comment: Never a tester can judge himself that his product is defect free.